# Googlesheets Apps Script Hyperlink within the Googlesheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I want to set up a code that hyperlinks to a cell location within the googlesheet and labels it the cell location (A1 Notation)

`sheetname.getRange(Lrow, 9)
.setValue('=hyperlink("#gid='+ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
+'&range='+"'"+sheet.getName()+"'"+'!'+sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()+'"
,"'+sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()+'")'`);

This works, but when clicking on it, it does not take you to the active cell, it only takes you to the correct sheet.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using this method:

```
sheetname.getRange(Lrow, 10)
.setValue('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'
+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getid()
+'/edit#gid='+ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
+'&range='+rangeset.getA1Notation()+'")');
```